# Setting sudo rights for an Icinga2 Service

Tags: linux, debian, sudo, icinga2

I have icinga2 installed on 3 Servers, all with debian stretch. On one Server I have glusterfs-Server running and would like to monitor it with icinga2. From the icinga2 website I downloaded the check_cluster service / script.

For it to work I need sudo rights. I set them but I only get an error message in icinga2:

```
command = [ "/usr/bin/sudo", PluginDir + "/check_cluster -h 1 -c 2 -d 0,0,0" ]

We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

#1) Respect the privacy of others.
#2) Think before you type.
#3) With great power comes great responsibility.

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

The sudo rights for the user are: ( in /etc/sudoers)

```
Defaults:nagios !requiretty
nagios ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/gluster
Cmnd_Alias CHECK_CLUSTER= /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_cluster
nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: CHECK_CLUSTER
```

I don't know wheter or not the nagio user has a password and if that is the problem.
This is from the /varlog/auth.log

```
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): conversation failed
sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): auth could not identify password for [nagios]
sudo:   nagios : command not allowed ; TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_cluster -h 1 -c 2 -d 0,0,0
```

What I don't want to do is, give nagios full permission fro everything with

```
nagios ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

What should I do? What rights would you recommend me setting?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
Cmnd_Alias CHECK_CLUSTER=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_cluster -h 1 -c 2 -d 0,0,0
```

since that is what user nagios is trying to execute with sudo.